# htacces - subdomain with get parameters

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

i want to rewrite a subdomain with get parameters.
My subdomain like :

vouchers.domain.com

This is my called domain:

vouchers.domain.com?url=test.de

This file get zero or one parameter

vouchers.php

My first try looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} vouchers.domain.com(.*?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !vouchers.php
RewriteRule ^$ vouchers.php?url=%1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

But it doesn't work.
Could anyone help me to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^vouchers\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^vouchers\.php$ vouchers.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,NC]
```